# Promise never gets resolved in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, html5-canvas

I have a asyn function in which I call another function that return a promise and also calls to another async function. Here is the code:

```
async function asyncAwaitRepeat(index) {
    if(index < 9) {
      
            await promise_animate(rectPointer); // the promise_animate return a promise
            
            await asyncAwaitRepeat(index + 1); // but my promise_animate never gets resolved
        

    }
}

asyncAwaitRepeat(asyncAwaitRepeatindex);
```

since I have some asynchronous code to execute so I cannot  invoke resolve() directly.
so I use call back

```
function promise_animate (index) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
       
        animate(index, () => {resolve});  // since animate function is a asynchronous so we 
                                        //cannot directly resolve() it
    })
}
```

and the animate function itself is async doing a bunch of asynchronous stuff

```
async function animate(rectIndex, animationPromiseFulfilled) {
    if(rectIndex < 8) {
        
        await promise_hightlight(rectIndex, "red");
        
        if( rectArray[rectIndex].value > rectArray[rectIndex+1].value ) {
            await promise_hightlight(rectIndex, "red");
            
          // doing a bunch of asynchronous stuff

           await animate(rectIndex+1, animationPromiseFulfilled); // << Here i call the 
                                                               // function recursively
    }
    else if(rectIndex == 8) {
   
        await promise_hightlight(rectIndex, "red");
        
        if( rectArray[rectIndex].value > rectArray[rectIndex+1].value ) {
            await promise_hightlight(rectIndex, "red");
          
            // some more asynchronous stuff 
            
        }   
        await promise_hightlight(rectIndex, "green");               
        rectPointer = 0;
        animationPromiseFulfilled("the animation function resolved");//<< the promise 
                                                                     //resolve done 
    }
     
}
```

But the fullfiled() is not doing its work and not resolving. Pls help

Comment: `animate(index, () => {resolve});` is the problem; it needs to be `animate(index, () => { resolve() });` or `animate(index, () => resolve());` or `animate(index, resolve);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your resolve never getting called so you have to try like that:

```
 function promise_animate (index) {
        return new Promise(async(resolve) => {
            resolve(await animate(index));  
        })
  }
```

Comment: thank you so mush for the code, I implemented you version and it is working. But you said resolve is never getting called , nah that's not true in the debugger mode I saw it being called but christ knows why it wasn't resolving

Comment: Okay, np Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

For this particular example I would try something like this, this will make sure the first promise is resolved before it moves on to the next one. You currently have your promises running parallel. Depending on your data you might not need asynchronous functions for this anyways.

```
 (async (index) => {
if(index<9){
Promise.all([promise_animate(rectPointer),asyncAwaitRepeat(index + 1)]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});

}

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but can you try below code. You can call resolve method. It will not trigger immediately.

```
function promise_animate (index) {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
      animate(index, () => resolve());  
   })
}
```

Comment: First of all welcome to the community. But I am already doing what you said : )

Comment: @Yuseff No you aren't. This is the best answer. Also, the line can be shortened to `animate(index, resolve)`